# how to add precise tolerance when comparing two images with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to compare two images with OpenCV and python. One is a reference [image: Reference], the second is a sample:
[image: Sample].

I locate the sample in the reference using cv2.matchTemplate.

For each occurence I crop the picture, convert the reference in blue, and the sample in red,
then use "cv2.bitwise_and" to superimpose both pictures,
then remove "black" pixels to better "see" the differences.
Here is the result for the second occurence:[image: Output]

As you can see there is a small offset between the two pictures, so I can still read "A O" in red and in blue (white is perfect).
I would like to tolerate this offset, and only see the missing "B" and the small dot on the right of the "O"
How can I do that?

The "red" is a printed and then scanned image.
I want to check the quality of my printer.

Comment: You might use template matching to align the two images first.

Comment: Please **read** the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: align the pictures. try ECC refinement. that'll improve the situation. then it's morphology time.

Comment: that illustration isn't confusing. don't interpret our advice to mean we didn't understand. you've been clear about what it is. that is understood. -- you might not think it's an alignment problem but we're saying it is, because alignment will reduce this issue. you seem to think that alignment means translation only. it does not. alignment commonly encompasses more degrees of freedom. -- this question is headed for closure until you provide source data, and your research and attempts. basically, review [ask]. I'm not gonna reiterate that.

Comment: based on the current version of the question, I remain with my previous advice of morphology to remove the "debris". generate a mask, apply "opening".

Comment: I've tried that but never succeeded in retrieving the small dot just after the "O", it always disappear if I do an "opening"

Comment: that difference is about as small as the deviations around edges that are due to stretching of the picture, subpixel misalignment, differences in rendering, ... -- if I figured out a solution for you, that would involve alignment and specific operations to suppress differences near edges that are present in both pictures. I *remember* that you didn't want alignment. -- this doesn't help in "checking the quality of a printer".